# Segmentation violation: while(fgets(buffer,15,statfile)!=NULL){};

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fgets

This code works for several thousand calls in a row if the r's are addressed sequentially. It works for a few hundred in a row if the r's are selected randomly.

However, at some point in the random r's, I get a segmentation violation. I am not sure what could be causing this since it works fine almost all of the time.

```
*** Break *** segmentation violation
Segmentation fault
```

The crash occurs at fgets.

```
int fsize(int r, double VME, std::string* filepath) {
  FILE *statfile;
  std::stringstream streamfilename;
  std::stringstream streamcommand;
  string* filename = new string;
  std::string command;
  char buffer [15];
  char charsize;
  streamfilename.str("");
  streamfilename << *filepath << "run" << r << "-" << VME << ".dat";
  *filename = streamfilename.str();
  streamcommand.str("");
  streamcommand << "stat -c " << "%s " << *filename;
  command = streamcommand.str();
  const char * charcommand = command.c_str();
  statfile = popen(charcommand, "r");
  cout << "Test 5\n";
  while(fgets(buffer,15,statfile)!=NULL){}; CRASH OCCURS HERE
  cout << "Test 6\n";
  int* filesize = new int;
  *filesize = atoi(buffer);
  pclose(statfile);
  return *filesize;
}
```

What is the cause of the segmentation fault?

Comment: Is statfile valid? Moreover...why mixing C and C++?

Comment: If you check the return value of popen() you will likely see that it failed.  statfile will be NULL and that is your road to ruin.

Comment: Adriano: Can you be more specific about C? I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: `I am not sure what could be causing this since it works fine almost all of the time.` "Working almost all of the time" is not an indicator of anything. The effects of memory corruption are unpredictable.

Comment: What would you suggest as replacements for fgets and popen? I don't mind rewriting the method but I am not sure what is better.

Comment: You should use a debugger and see which variables have an unexpected value. `popen` is probably right for what you're trying to do, but it might be failing.

Comment: Variable 'filesize' suggests this code was written with insufficient understanding of pointers and memory management. Makes me fear the worst for the rest of the program. Time for some serious code reviews.

Comment: Rudd: What is the issue with filesize?

Comment: You are leaking `filesize`. `filename` too. Your code has two occurrences of `new` (for no good reason), but none of `delete`.

Comment: Igor is right. These 3 lines of code: `int* filesize = new int; *filesize = atoi(buffer); return *filesize;` could be replaced by just one line: `return atoi(buffer);`. If this is over your head, you should take time to learn. I'm not judging anyone, this stuff is hard to grok, but it is essential when programming in C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statFile` is probably `NULL`.

If you would like to get filesize, you should consider the C function :

```
 int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

It will avoid to fork the command, and parsing its result.